Get all records in a mongo collection returns empty array
I have a mongo database named "photos-album", and a collection named "users".
I'm trying to fetch all users in mongo, but I get empty array although I do have users in my users collection.
I took the connection string in app.module.ts from Mongo Compass so I think that the connection string is correct. And I don't get any errors.
What am I missing?
The user document (in Mongo Compass) looks like:
_id: ObjectId(string);
name: string;
username: string;
email: string;

users.schema.ts:
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
});


users.interface.ts:
export interface User {
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
}

users.module.ts:
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: 'User', schema: UserSchema, collection: 'users' },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}

app.module.ts:
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@photos-album.m6dqk.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=photos-album',
    ),
    UsersModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

users.service.ts:
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    const users = await this.userModel.find().exec();
    console.log('users:', users);
    return users;
  }
}


Did you name your cluster photos-album too (as opposed to the default Cluster0 etc)? If so then it looks like just adding photos-album after the trailing slash should get you connected to that database instead of the default test database so try mongodb+srv://<u>:<p>@photos-album.m6dqk.mongodb.net/photos-album?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=photos-album
